# send email when exceptions occur in catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, email

i am working on this. monitor tomcat log file called "Catalina.out" for "Exception" error. The script should send us the E-mail as soon as it finds the string "Exception" in the file. Any thoughts?

Can this be done via tomcat/log4j?

Comment: i guess its possible to do logger .you can define the log levels based on level we could do the logger and different function.make a try and post it.

Comment: Use a log appender to send an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 = 1 ]
do
    rcode="`tail -n 1000 catalina.out 2>&1 | grep -o Exception`"
    if [ "$rcode" = "Exception" ]
    then
            echo "Something went wrong." \
            | mail -s "your subject" mail@mailaddress.com
    fi
    sleep 180
done
```

There are certainly some improvements to be done. E.g. the "-n 1000" or sleeping for 180 seconds. But it should do for a start.

Comment: That will do if you run your server on Linux/Unix. For a platform-independent solution, take a look at the [log4j SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender).

Comment: Ok, and that will do, if you are still on log4j

Comment: You can use whatever logging engine you want as long as you make Tomcat understand that (assuming you want to capture Tomcat errors as well, not only your application errors). I prefer Logback (and SLF4J) in my projects, but Log4J is easier to configure on Tomcat.